# Loop for frame extraction matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, video, jpeg

Im currently trying to make a loop to do the same action to multiply videofiles. Currently my code looks like this:

```
    close all
clear all
clc
movFiles = dir('*.mov');
numFiles = length(movFiles);
mydata = cell(1,numFiles);

% mydata = zeros(numFiles);
for k = 1:numFiles
    mydata{1,k} = VideoReader(movFiles(k).name);
end


for k=1:numFiles
    figure;
    video = read(mydata{k},[1 Inf]);
    for img = 60:60:360; 
        filename=strcat('File',num2str(img),'.jpg'); 
        b = read(mydata{k}, img); 
        imwrite(b,filename);
    end
end
```

The problem is that the frames get overwritten so what i need is a way to not make that happened. The moviefiles are named 1-200 so the filename i would like is something like 1framenr, 2framenr. Hope that somebody can help me with that

Comment: "...it goes wrong...". Goes wrong how? Please be specific.

Comment: Why the inconsistency between `mydata{1,k}` in the first loop and `mydata{k}` twice in the second?

Comment: I have edited the post now so the problem is more clear. I can get it to extract the frames but the files are overwritten, im pretty sure that is't from filename and down that something goes wring with the naming of the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are defining the filename for each frame inside the loop. If you look at the line:

```
filename=strcat('File',num2str(img),'.jpg');
```

It is only composed of the frame number (`img`), which will repeat for every video file. Try replacing that line with following:

```
filename = ['Video_' num2str(k) '_frame_' num2str(img) '.jpg'];
```

This will give you files called Video_1_frame_1.jpg, Video_1_frame_2.jpg, etc.